# Chiudere e staccare

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, single-words

Buongiorno,

È mai capitato che vedendoti pensieroso una persona ti abbia chiesto di "chiudere" o "staccare"? Ma cosa significano esattamente queste parole in italiano, non mi è chiaro. Se uno non pensa quando è sveglio allora che cavolo fa. Non è un' illusione l'idea che una persona possa smettere di pensare?

Grazie.

Comment: Voto per la chiusura [sic] della domanda perché è veramente incomprensible cosa tu stia chiedendo. Se riformuli la domanda in modo che sia più chiara, magari possiamo rispondere.

Comment: Sto semplicemente chiedendo cos'è il significato esatto di queste due parole relative al pensiero. Penso di essere stato abbastanza chiaro.

Comment: Per esempio potresti includere alcuni esempi d'uso? Veramente non riesco a capire a cosa tu stia facendo riferimento.

Comment: @DenisNardin: Forsi si tratta di una raccomandazione di "staccare la spina".

Comment: Sì, forse, anche se io come esempio ho sentito suo dirmi "chiudi" o "stacca" quando me ne stavo zitto a pensare.

Comment: Forse puoi fornire una risposta col significato di "staccare la spina". Grazie.

Comment: Cerco di farlo.

Comment: Jimmy, quando la gente ti dice delle cose strane, perché non chiedi a loro che cosa intendono, anziché a degli sconosciuti su internet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Immagino che si faccia riferimento all'espressione "staccare la spina" che, secondo [Garzanti Linguistica](http://www.garzantilinguistica.it/ricerca/?q=staccare) (nella sezione "Polirematica",
soltanto disponibile con un abbonamento attivo, ma che si può visualizzare nella copia cache di Google) può significare

> smettere di lavorare o di pensare a qualcosa, rilassarsi

Se qualcuno ti ha visto molto pensieroso, può dirti questo con l'intenzione di raccomandarti di non pensare a tuoi problemi e cercare di rilassarti.

Comment: Un po' un problema per una persona che si rilassa pensando. :-)