# È corretto abbreviare una polirematica?

Tags: word-usage

Buongiorno,

Una ricerca su Google ci mostra che la polirematica è:

> Polirematica:
>
> In linguistica, sintagma costituito da due o più parole, con
>   significato autonomo rispetto ai singoli termini che lo costituiscono
>   (per es. acqua e sapone, conto corrente, salto nel buio, alzare il
>   gomito).

Volevo sapere, è comune o corretto abbreviare una polirematica alla prima parola che la compone, mantenendo allo stesso tempo il significato espresso dalla polirematica intera?

Per esempio, posso dire

> stacca!

invece di

> stacca la spina!

?

Se sì, in quali parti d'Italia è comune questa cosa? O è per caso un costrutto importato da una lingua straniera impropriamente adattato alla lingua italiana?

Comment: Questa domanda non ha senso. In italiano ci sono migliaia di espressioni polirematiche: alcune si “abbrevieranno”, altre no, altre cambieranno senso se lo si fa.

Comment: @DaG Non sarà la domanda migliore di questo sito, ma "non ha senso" mi sembra eccessivo. È perfettamente chiara: chiede se si può fare una certa cosa ben definita. La risposta è "no, non si può fare in generale", ma questo non invalida la domanda.

Comment: Hai ragione, @FedericoPoloni, la domanda è chiarissima, ma così generica da essere inutile. È come domandare “Gli animali volano?” La risposta “Non tutti” sarebbe impeccabile, ma a sua volta così generica che non sarebbe di grandissimo aiuto. La categoria “too broad” è prevista esattamente per questo tipo di domande.

Comment: Quindi @FedericoPoloni dice di no, mentre @ DaG dice di si, anche se non capisco cosa intenda con "altre cambieranno senso se lo si fa". Forse delle risposte con altri esempi sarebbero molto apprezzate. Grazie.

Comment: Infatti, @JimmyJoslington, che è chiara l'ho detto anch'io. La mia critica, e il motivo per cui propongo di chiuderla, è che è troppo generica (“too broad”). Poni la domanda per una specifica espressione, o al massimo per un piccolo insieme di espressioni, magari che hanno in comune una stessa parola. (Comunque DaG non “dice di sì”, dice “dipende”.)

Comment: @Dag, è interessante quello che dici, solo che non riuscirei a pensare a delle sottocategorie di espressioni composte che possono essere abbreviate, ma io non conosco l'italiano molto bene. Forse tu che lo conosci meglio mi potresti illuminare. Grazie.

Comment: “Stacca” non è solo “stacca la spina”, fra le altre cose che si possono dire su questa domanda.

Comment: Quindi, @egreg, ci sono anche delle altre polirematiche con "stacca", che rendono l'espressione"stacca" ambigua?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spesso nel parlare e anche nello scrivere si usano frasi incomplete o non perfettamente corrette, nella logica e anche per quanto riguarda l'informazione fornita.
Di fatto il messaggio arriva correttamente all'interlocutore, che lo completa  delle parti mancanti attraverso la propria interpretazione.
Ad esempio se allo sportello bancario chiedo al cassiere che mi conosce: "Mi puoi dire quanto ho sul conto?" Lui mi risponderà fornendomi l'importo a saldo del mio conto corrente.

Potrebbe rispondermi più correttamente con: "Se ti riferisici al tuo conto corrente presso di noi, te lo posso dire, altrimenti no." Senza fornirmi l'informazione che mi serve, ma in quel caso penserei che è poco intelligente, e perderei tempo a fargli una domanda più precisa, del tipo: 
"Per favore dimmi l'importo in euro del saldo contabile del mio conto corrente presso di voi al momento attuale, e nel caso in cui questo non corrisponda al saldo disponibile, elencami le eventuali operazioni non ancora contabilizzate."

Non esiste una regola grammaticale che stabilisce quando si possano omettere delle informazioni, è una scelta libera di chi formula una frase, basata sulla sua esperienza e magari su altri fattori, come fretta, pignoleria, grado di confidenza, importanza della comunicazione. Il rischio legato a questa scelta è di non farsi capire, o di perdere tempo inutilmente, o ancora di essere noiosi.

Ad esempio se al direttore della stessa banca pongo la domanda: "Che informazioni avete sul mio conto?" Non è chiaro se sto parlando del mio conto corrente o della mia persona, e facilmente ci saranno dei malintesi, probabilmente l'interlocutore mi chiederà dei chiarimenti prima di rispondere.

Questo vale per le frasi polirematiche come per altri tipi di frase.

Nel caso di "staccare la spina", posso dire a un mio collega: "Ho lavorato troppo oggi, ho bisogno di staccare" e lui capirà perfettamente cosa voglio dire. In altri contesti la frase potrebbe non essere chiara se incompleta.

Comment: Neanche a farlo apposta, [qui](http://blog.terminologiaetc.it/2017/10/02/burocratese-mezzi-pubblici/) c'è un altro esempio, ancorché in burocratichese: “titolo” per “titolo di viaggio”.

Answer (score 1):

"Stacca la spina" è una polirematica? Forse sbaglio io, ma non la vedo come una polirematica.

Per risponderti: non credo si possano in generale abbreviare, se non in casi particolari. Ad esempio, prendiamo "biglietto da visita". Se siamo in un contesto in cui già stavamo parlando di biglietti da visita, posso immaginare di dire "ti lasco il mio biglietto", perché che sia un biglietto da visita è sottointeso. Però non la definirei una cosa di uso comune.

E comunque la cosa non si applica a tutti i casi. Se anche stiamo già parlando di "lune di miele", per esempio, non posso chiederti "allora, come è andata la luna?" Suonerebbe strano. Al limite può suonare scherzoso, ma di sicuro non corretto.

Per alcuni casi particolari l'abbreviazione può funzionare, ad esempio invece di "cartoni animati" si può dire "cartoni", ma in questo caso penso che sia perché nel linguaggio ormai la parola "cartoni" da sola ha già assunto il significato di "cartoni animati".

Concludendo: se non usi abbreviazioni, non sbagli.
Se usi abbreviazioni, molto probabilmente suoneranno strane o incomprensibili.

Comment: [A quel che pare](https://italian.stackexchange.com/a/8622/37), il dizionario Garzanti registra “staccare la spina” proprio come espressione polirematica. E comunque, visto che ha un uso figurato indipendente dall'azione di separare un oggetto da un altro e dalle spine, lo è di fatto.

Comment: @LisaD, grazie per la risposta, ma non ho capito perché pensi che "staccare la spina" non sia un'espressione polirematica. Quale parte della definizione di polirematica fornita è in disaccordo?

Comment: Anche per me "allora, come è andata la luna?" suona scherzoso. Altri esempi?